# No sound coming from midi keyboard

Tags: midi

I have a MIDI keyboard set up, I installed the drivers, and all the right lights are flashing, but when I press a key no sound comes out, how can I remedy this situation?

My model is the PCR-M50, if anyone can help I would be most grateful.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information before anyone could possibly help you.

Comment: What operating system does your computer have? (Windows XP?) What music software are you running on that computer?

Comment: Windows 7, 64 bit. And... none. When it worked before I could just plug it in and play (which is all I want to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect your MIDI keyboard to a MIDI synthesizer (either software or hardware).

If your keyboard didn't include one, you might use something like [FluidSynth](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/fluidsynth/)

[Music On My PC](http://www.musiconmypc.co.uk/art_keyboard_connection.php) explains some of the basics

Answer (score 1):

Check that the keyboard is set up to produce the sounds on your computer. If the lights are flashing, the MIDI signal is being processed, but you may not have your system set up to output the sound.